# What is the expansion for the abbreviation “ИК”?

Tags: перевод, значения, сокращения

The following image is from my textbook:

[image: Various examples of the stress patterns for some short phrases. Each example is prefaced with “ИК-1”, “ИК-2”, or “ИК-3”.]

It’s not hard to guess that it’s about the stress pattern of words, but what do “ИК-1”, “ИК-2”, “ИК-3”, etc. stand for? There is no explanation in my book about it.

Comment: This sample definitely requires more explanation. It cannot be understood with no context. Probably, language teatcher skills are required for being able to understand this.

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич or some knowledge in Russian linguistic terminology ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**ИК** stands for **интонационная конструкция** (intonation construction), and the numbers refer to particular tone combinations:

http://fsi-russian.yojik.eu/ch03s11.xhtml

Comment: короткий и простой но отличный ответ! спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 4):

"ИК" stands for "интонационная конструкция" (intonation structure), although I have to admit that this isn't a wide-known term. It's just that some Russian-language linguists developed classification counting different intonations in Russian.

You'll find one such classification [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F):